# Addition of PIC 9 variable with space not causing ABEND S0C7

Tags: cobol

I expected the ADD instruction in the following COBOL program to trigger an ABEND S0C7. However the program terminated normally and the ouput was quite surprising.

**The SYSIN in the JCL**

```
//SYSIN   DD *
5
//* There is only the character 5 in the SYSIN (well, followed by a newline character of course)
```

**The COBOL program**

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
77 X                     PIC 9(10).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    ACCEPT X
*   This addition did not trigger an ABEND S0C7
    ADD 1                TO X
    DISPLAY 'X = ' X
    STOP RUN
    .
```

**The output**

```
X = 5000000001
```

**I then ran the program in a debugger**

The ACCEPT statement moved a '5' in the leftmost character of X and spaces in the others on the right. So to be more specific, X looked like this after the ACCEPT:

```
'9         '   <-- These are the 10 characters of X
 0987654321    <-- These are the bytes numbered for clarity
```

I thought maybe the display of X of my debugger had a bug and showed me space characters instead of zeros but no. I checked the memory at X and it really contained nine bytes with the value 0x40 which are indeed ' ' characters in EBCDIC.

**I then checked the assembly generated by the compiler**

Well, I forgot to copy the exact output from my machine at work but here is the assembly code in pseudo language.

```
* ADD 1                TO X
    PACK  XP, X         * Pack X to XP
    AP    XP, ONEP      * XP += 1
    UNPK  XP, X         * Unpack XP to X
```

- ONEP is the address where 1 is stored in a packed format.

**So, what am I missing here?**

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT #1 - February 26th - I checked the exact assembly code**

Monday morning. Got the assembly code from my machine at work...

```
*     ADD 1       TO X
PKA   672(R13),152(10,R9)      PACK ASCII  Y,X
AP    682(6,R13),1072(1,R13)   ADD PACKED  Y,1
UNPK  152(10,R9),682(6,R13)    UNPACK      X,Y
OI    161(,R9),X'F0'
```

... and the compile option [ZONEDATA(NOPFD)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.2?topic=ecco-zonedata) was used.

Comment: `X` has ten digits. Why should it abend when it is declared to contain ten digits, i.e. `PIC 9(10)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process non formatted numeric variable from SYSIN DD from JCL in COBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77916129/how-to-process-non-formatted-numeric-variable-from-sysin-dd-from-jcl-in-cobol)

Comment: @RickSmith This answer indeed explain the part of the ACCEPT. I have also just learned about the PACK instruction from Punctilious Programmer (he has a video about PACK https://punctiliousprogrammer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Pack.mp4 ).

Comment: I still do not understand how the ADD works fine. Here is why. PACK starts by swapping the two nibbles of the right source byte and put them in the right byte of the destination. So the 0x40 of X becomes 0x04 in the right byte of XP which is an invalid byte for a packed decimal.

Comment: What are your compile options?  You seem to be compiling on an IBM Z machine, so presuming Enterprise COBOL is your compiler, you might want to look at the effect of ZONEDATA and INVDATA in the Programming Guide.

Comment: @cschneid I am compiling for an IBM mainframe that's all I know. I did this at work and I don't know much about the hardware nor the specific options because we can't customize much except OPTIMIZE and SSRANGE I think. Monday I'll check the exact assembly code from the compile output to be sure if I didn't miss any instruction. But at the COBOL level, I find this behaviour very strange. However I do know that it's version 4 of COBOL.

Comment: The compile options are usually listed at the beginning of the program listing. I hope your employer is not still using version 4 of Enterprise COBOL, as it was withdrawn from service on 2022-04-30.   If you are still using version 4, then neither of those compile options I mentioned apply.

Comment: @cschneid I edited my post with the exact assembly code and found out that the compile option ZONEDATA(NOPFD) was used. The pack instruction is not the regular PACK but PASCK ASCII. The result of PACK ASCII on X is a valid COMP-3 integer so the ADD does not generate a data exception.

Comment: @Itsbananas The assembly code shows that the compiler is generating a "Pack ASCII" instruction, which by definition (see Principles of Operation) works as follows: "....The **implied positive sign (1100 binary)** and the source digits are placed at the first-operand location." Therefore the sign nibble is always valid, indicating a positive number